# Is there a better way or more efficient way to write this IF statement?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I need a way to get the return number to increase by "1" after every increment of "10".  Is there a more efficient way to do this other than:

```
=SUM(
IF(AC11<10,0,
IF(AC11<20,1,
IF(AC11<30,2,
IF(AC11<40,3,
IF(AC11<50,4,
IF(AC11<60,5,
IF(AC11<70,6,
IF(AC11<80,7,
IF(AC11<90,8,
IF(AC11<100,9,
IF(AC11<110,10,
IF(AC11<120,11,
IF(AC11<130,12,
IF(AC11<140,13,
IF(AC11<150,14,
IF(AC11<160,15,)
))))))))))))))))
```

Comment: Checkout `IFS` on the Google Sheets Function List.If you need further help add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask]. By the way, looking for "better ways" usually is subjective. Please describe what means better in this case (improved readability, shorter formula...)

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a improved way to create the following function in google sheets:   =SUM(IF(AC11<10,0,IF(AC11<20,1,IF(AC11<30,2,IF(AC11<40,3,IF(AC11<50,4,IF(AC11<60,5,IF(AC11<70,6,IF(AC11<80,7,IF(AC11<90,8,IF(AC11<100,9,IF(AC11<110,10,IF(AC11<120,11,IF(AC11<130,12,IF(AC11<140,13,IF(AC11<150,14,IF(AC11<160,15)))))))))))))))))

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a much simpler way to do what are you trying to do:

```
=INT(AC11/10)
```

Good luck!

Comment: I get an error that says INT only takes one argument and it reads the ,10 as a second argument:   

Yes, there is a much simpler way to do what are you trying to do:

=INT(AC11,10)

Comment: Thank you again for the suggestion.  I found the answer and used:  =INT(AC11/10)